# DataBinding Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

Could some one please help me out with this. I've been struggling with this error for a couple of hours and couldn't seems to figure it out. Any help will really be appreciated!

### The following are my WebConfig and Back-end codes.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DB01Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.EntityClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\DB01.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<connectionStrings/>
```

And code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB01Entities"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Course_ID, Course_Institution, Course_Name, Course_Description, Course_CutOffPoints, Course_English, Course_Mathematics, Course_Science from tblCourse", con);
            con.Open();
            DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Course_Name";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Course_ID";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();

        }
    }
}
}
```

---

Picture for the Error Message.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkrOT.png)

Once again, thank you very much for helping out!

Comment: might try to change in your connection string : provider=System.Data.EntityClient  to provider=System.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you !